# pivot_wider causing "! Can't subset columns that don't exist." Error in R

Tags: r

I have data that I'm trying to pivot in R. But when I run my code, I get a Can't subset columns that don't exist error. My data currently looks like this, however, there are hundreds of different Titles, not just three as my simplified data below looks like.

```
ID    Title         Training_Time    Percent_Complete

1     New             1                    100
1     Hazmat          5                    100
1     Management      12                   100
```

And I would like for it to look like this, and if possible also include Columns for Percent Complete, though I can make do with just having the days it took to complete training, like I have below.

```
ID    Training_New     Training_Hazmat          Training_Managerment

1         1                   5                        12
```

I've tried several different versions of the code below, based on stackoverflow responses to similar questions.

```
LMS_df <- LMS_df %>%
tidyr::pivot_wider(-ID,
  names_from = LMS_df$Title,
  values_from = LMS_df$Training_Time
)
```

Any advice on getting rid of this error? Do I need to create new columns for every training title that I have in my dataset?

Comment: Just remove `LMS_df` from your arguments to `pivot_wider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a small reproducible example from the data provided by the original poster. The name of the data frame in dollar syntax (i.e. `LMS_df$`) is not needed. Without, it works so far. A name prefix can be added with `names_prefix = "Training_"`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
~ID,    ~Title,       ~Training_Time,  ~Percent_Complete,
1,     "New",         1,                100,
1,     "Hazmat",      5,                100,
1,     "Management",  12,               100
)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(-ID,
    names_from = Title,
    values_from = Training_Time,
    names_prefix = "Training_"
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   Percent_Complete Training_New Training_Hazmat Training_Management
#>              <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>               <dbl>
#> 1              100            1               5                  12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A final note: This is a special case as `Percent_Complete` is equally 100 for all `Title`s. Otherwise, you would get an individual row for each percentage and an `NA` for all non-matching cases.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Title,
              values_from = Training_Time, 
              names_glue = "Training_{Title}") %>% 
  select(-ID)
```

```
 Percent_Complete Training_New Training_Hazmat Training_Management
             <int>        <int>           <int>               <int>
1              100            1               5                  12
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df), Percent_Complete ~ paste0("Training_", Title), value.var = "Training_Time")
```

-output

```
   Percent_Complete Training_Hazmat Training_Management Training_New
1:              100               5                  12            1
```